# What's the equivalent of bash parentheses at the command line in powershell?

Tags: powershell

in bash I can do this

```
cd some-folder
(cd some-other-folder && export foo=bar && exec-some-command)
```

When it's done I'll be back in the state I started, I'll still be in 'some-folder' not 'some-other-folder' and my environment will be what it was before I executed the commands (foo will not be assigned to bar)

Is there a way to do the same easily in powershell?

I tried

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {cd "some-other-folder"; $env:foo="bar"; exec-some-command}
```

but it affected the current process instead of doing it in another process.

Comment: vs a hard cd (aka Set-Location), you can leverage pushd (Push-Location) and popd (Pop-Location)  in your code. See the PowerShell help files for explanation, details, and examples.

Comment: thanks but push-location and pop-location assume success where as `()` doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your commands are non-interactive, it seems that *jobs* would be the closest equivalent as they do basically run a background subshell and optionally return its output:

```
sh$  (cd folder && export foo=bar && some-command) & wait

PS>  Start-Job {cd "folder"; $env:foo="bar"; some-command} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

```
sh$  (cd foo && do_bar) & pid=$!; <...>; wait $pid

PS>  $job = Start-Job {cd foo; do_bar}; <...>; Wait-Job $job
```

Unfortunately, jobs do not correctly inherit the working directory in PowerShell 5 which is included with Windows (though they do in PowerShell 7 which is available for install [from GitHub](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1)). In PS5, all jobs appear to start at ~\Documents instead.

The `-WorkingDirectory` parameter to Start-Job is also a PS7 addition. A possible workaround for PS5 is to provide `$pwd` as an input object:

```
$pwd | start-job {cd; cd "folder"; ...} | receive-job ...
```

Comment: Thank you!  BTW is there any option to pass in the current shell's variables? In bash `FOO=123<enter>(echo $FOO)<enter>` works. But `$FOO=123<enter>Start-Job {echo $FOO} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob<enter>` does not

Comment: @gman: Apparently there is `$using:FOO`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075943/powershell-pass-variable-to-start-job